# Who manages (creates, allocates memory, etc.) R sessions / R processes within OpenCPU?

Tags: r, apache, opencpu, rapache

We have an OpenCPU cloud server, installed on a RedHat server with Apache 2.0 and rApache, which runs some quite memory- and processing-intensive calculations. Our app runs rather slowly (slower than on a less powerful laptop) - we think this is because of the memory allocation on the server.
For this reason we parallelized the app for the server (using the `parallel` package), but even though normally one can run many (more than 20) parallel R jobs on the server, our app can only run around 18.

In order to understand what is going on, my question is: when I call an R function through the OpenCPU web interface, which component of the server creates/spawns R processes and manages their memory allocation? Is it `r_mod` or the Apache server itself, through some other modules? Does the `Prefork` MPM have an effect on this (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688149/how-many-requests-can-be-processed-simultaneously-by-r-opencpu))? Which part of this work is done by OpenCPU?

I read the OpenCPU documentation, rApache documentation, all stackoverflow questions on OpenCPU, but I didn't manage to understand how R processes are managed in particular. Sorry if I missed something, I'd be really grateful if anybody could point me to the source of this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slowness can be a result of application requiring packages that are not being preloaded, hence they need to get loaded for each request, over and over again.

To speed things up, try adding your package to the `preload` in `/etc/opencpu/server.conf` or add preprocessing R code to `/etc/opencpu/Rprofile` that loads the required packages / data.

Answering your question:

- Apache2 prefork maintains a pool of worker processes. The size of the pool `n` is configurable in Apache using `StartServers`, `MinSpareServers`, `MaxSpareServers`, `MaxRequestWorkers`, and so on. Because each R worker uses a lot of resources this shouldn't be set too high.
- Upon start, each apache2 worker process starts a new private R process. Each R process then loads the opencpu package and it's dependencies, `preload` packages, and runs `/etc/opencpu/Rprofile`. Hence in total it uses `n` times the amount of memory it take to load those things in R.
- Each request gets executed in a random worker, within a temporary sandbox fork. If the request requires R packages that are not preloaded, those have to be loaded on demand. This makes the requests slow.
- Once the request is completed, temporary sandbox fork is killed and the worker is cleaned up.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Do I understand it correctly: Prefork (the Apache module) controls the creation of **as well as memory allocation** for each child process, and if there's too many of them, this may limit resources for other child processes?

As for the preloading of packages, we logged our processes, and I think that takes negligible amount of time - what takes the most time is loading and processing of data from an SQL database, so maybe the existance of other,  idle child processes may be what is slowing this down.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Any program allocates the amount of memory it needs, except for when the system runs out of memory, then the OS may kill the process. If you are running too many workers you may run out of memory, but that will result http 500 errors, not slowness.

Comment: Is your function returning or printing a lot of data? There might be overhead because of that because opencpu serializes and saves the session output.

Comment: I thought R sessions are somehow limited and these processes cannot allocate arbitrary amount of memory from the OS so perhaps that was causing the slow-down, and I thought maybe this was controlled through some Apache2 parameters. So if there are too many child processes with their own memory and this limits the needed memory for one R session, then there's an error instead of slow-down?

My functions are printing logs and returning a big data-frame in the end, but I don't think the logs are that many, and the session is slowed long before data output, but rather at data import from DB.

Comment: you said "Upon start, each apache2 worker process starts a new private R process. " - what did you mean by this, upon start of what? Start of OpenCPU? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Upon starting apache2.